# Inner div not stretching to outer div even with parent set as 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe I'm just tied and overlooking something really simple, but it seems my inner divs are not stretching to their parent element even though I have `height:100%` set for both the children and the parent. I am using bootstrap 3. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#testimonials {
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}

#testimonials > div {
    border-right: 1px solid #e25400;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="testimonials" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
    </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/d5JX7/1/ its a responsive design so you need to stretch it out to 1200px. I made the text in the first column shorter to demonstrate the shorter border length which I would ideally like to be symmetrical with the rest

Comment: You realise that if you set `#testimonials>div` to 100% height of `#testimonials` then the height `#testimonials` is going to increase 3 fold because there are 3 divs inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set height at 100%, some element in the html tree must have a fixed height or all parent elements must be set to 100%, including the `html` tag.

In your case, if you set `#testimonials` to, say `height:300px`, then your second rule should work.

Alternatively, set a height for the parent of `#testimonials`. If the parent of `#testimonials` is the `body` tag, set `html, body{ height:100%; }`

EDIT:

In the fiddle you posted, The neatest solution is to convert `#testimonials` into a table so that it's cells would automatically expand to the largest height.

You can do this with CSS only to preserve your markup. Just set `display:table` for `#testimonials;` and `display:table-cell;` for the divs

Comment: I thought this might be the case..Just wondering how I've never encountered this issue before..

Preferably I would like to avoid a fixed height because the content is dynamic, I guess I can use js...

Comment: You probably dont need JS. if you post a JS fiddle showing your html structure we can better see what you are doing and suggest a fix.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d5JX7/1/ its a responsive design so you need to stretch it out to 1200px. I made the text in the first column shorter to demonstrate the shorter border length which I would ideally like to be symmetrical with the rest

Comment: Okay when you say `#testimonials{height:100%;}` what are you trying to achieve? What's it supposed to look like?

Comment: Its more what the inner divs (columns) are supposed to look like, I want the shorter ones (shorter because of less content) to stretch out to the same height as the longer ones so the borders are symmetrical. I added height 100% to `#testimonials` hoping it would fix it. Only really concerned with the right borders, not so much the outer div

Comment: I see. It's tricky all right. I might settle for `#testimonials > div {min-height:120px;}` or to roughly the height of the tallest testimonial. Alternatively, you could convert `#testimonials` into a table and the cells would automatically expand to the largest height. You can do this with CSS only to preserve your markup. Look at `display:table` for `#testimonials` and `display:table-cell` for the divs

Comment: okay thanks for you help, I guess using a table is the most accurate solution without using JS, perhaps set that as the answer and i'll tick it?

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body{height:100%;}

#testimonials {
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

#testimonials > div {
    border-right: 1px solid #e25400;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/Kkg68/8/